# Create login as user and login as organization mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am building an app which requires register and login for user as well as org. I am using node js passport - local strategy for the same. I have created all views and made login with user to work but as I replicate the code for login as organization, I get unexpected errors or gets redirected to any other view.

Here is my app.js file

```
// Passport Config
require('./config/Orgpassport')(Orgpassport);
require('./config/passport')(passport);


// Express session
app.use(
  session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

// Passport middleware
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Connect flash
app.use(flash());
```

Here is my passport.js file

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// Load User model
const User = require('../models/User');

module.exports = function(passport) {
  passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
      console.log(passport);
      // Match user
      User.findOne({
        email: email
      }).then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'That email is not registered' });
        }

        // Match password
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, user);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
      done(err, user);
    });
  });
};
```

Here is my post request for login form.

```
router.post('/Orglogin', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/Orgdashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/org/Orglogin',
    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

I am able to login with user but not with organization?

Here is my Orgpassport.js file

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const Org = require('../models/Organization');

module.exports = function(Orgpassport) {
  Orgpassport.use(
    new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' }, (email, password, done) => {
      // Match org
      Org.findOne({
        email: email
      }).then(org => {
        if (!org) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'That email is not registered' });
        }

        // Match password
        bcrypt.compare(password, org.password, (err, isMatch) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          if (isMatch) {
            return done(null, org);
          } else {
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Password incorrect' });
          }
        });
      });
    })
  );

  Orgpassport.serializeUser(function(org, done) {
    done(null, org.id);
  });

  Orgpassport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    Org.findById(id, function(err, org) {
      done(err, org);
    });
  });
};
```

Here is the OrgLogin.ejs file

```
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-md-6 m-auto">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <h1 class="text-center mb-3"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i>  Login</h1>
      <% include ./partials/messages %>
      <form action="/org/Orglogin" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Password"
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
      </form>
      <p class="lead mt-4">
        No Account? <a href="/org/Orgregister">Register</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your front end add a `param` for example like `"org"` so that in your back end you will be able to identify that the request is for organization , and then in your org schema for add a boolean like `"isorganisation=true"` this will make you identify if the user who is trying to login is from org or not, next in your passport Local Strategy in this line add this new `LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' ,passReqToCallback:true}` this will allow you to get the `request` ,and then you can use that to implement the logic, use the parametere you set earlier`req,params.org`and check if it exist, if it does then verify if user in db and check if `isorganisation` is set to `true` if it is , verify user as normal , otherwise if `req.params` doesn't contain org it means it is not from org then you use normal user verification this way you don't need to use 2 local strategies and you can use two different models in this scenario

Comment: already done that. const passport = require('passport'); const Orgpassport = require('passport'); I was just passing two different variables. Main problem is with these two require statements only. Both of them work individually (when I comment anyone) but not both at the same time

Comment: i understand where the problem is however i would like to know why are you using the same strategy but twice !?

Comment: One for user verification and one for organization verification.

Comment: You don't need to use same strategy twice to verify user and organization , the verification is done by passport using the info stored in the db , which means you can store the data for user in for example a separate collection and the same for organization and the verification will be done by one strategy not duplicate

Comment: But as you can see, passport.js file takes only one db model i.e User Or Organization. How should I modify passport.js file so that it can authenticate both of them?

Comment: from your front end add a param for  example like "org" so that in your back end you will be able to identify that the request is for organization , and then in your org schema for add a boolean like `"isorganisation=true" `this will make you identify if the user who is trying to login is from org or not, next in your passport Local Strategy in this line add this   `new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'email' ,passReqToCallback:true}` this will allow you to get the request ,and then you can use that to implement the logic, use the parametere you et earlier` req,params.org `and check if it exist

Comment: if it does then verify if user in db and check if `isorganisation` is set to true if it is , verify user as normal , otherwise if `req.params` doesn't contain org it means it is not from org then you use normal user verification this way you don't need to use 2 local strategies and you can use two different models in this scenario

Comment: Thanks buddy @Sven.hig, writing passReqToCallback gives access to req object inside passport which means I can access req.url. Console.log(req.url) <= with this I can easily check if user or organization is trying to log in. There is no need to pass any param from frontend.

Comment: or you can do better pass a param in the url and then use req.params

Comment: i will be glad if you conceder accepting and upvoting the answer it will help others in the future

Comment: I have Upvoted. This is the flash that i see         Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.